# Apollo Cache Updates with TypeScript null checking

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I am using [apollo codgen](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling) to generate types for my graphql queries and using TS, I am finding that the generated types have lots of `null` values in them, such that my code becomes tons of `if` checks. Is this the way people are writing their graphql cache updates with TS?

```
this.props.mutate({
  variables,
  update: (proxy, { data }) => {
    // nulls all the way down so guarding against them with early return
    if (!data || !data.createContact || !data.createContact.contact) return;
    let newContactEdge = {
      node: { ...data.createContact.contact, __typename: 'Contact' },
      __typename: 'ContactEdge',
    };

    // read from cache
    let listCache = proxy.readQuery<ListContactsQuery>({ query: ChatAPI.queries.listContacts });

    // again nulls all the way down
    if (listCache && listCache.contacts && listCache.contacts.edges) {
      proxy.writeQuery({
        query: ChatAPI.queries.listContacts,
        data: {
          ...listCache,
          contacts: {
            ...listCache.contacts,
            edges: [newContactEdge, ...listCache.contacts.edges],
          },
        },
      });
    }
  },
})
```

This just feels wrong, before I knew if `cache` was not null, then the data would be there and wouldn't have to check all the way down.

For reference, here is the generated types for that `ListContactsQuery`

```
export interface ListContactsQuery_contacts_edges {
    __typename: "ContactEdge";
    /**
     * The item at the end of the edge.
     */
    node: ListContactsQuery_contacts_edges_node | null;
}
export interface ListContactsQuery_contacts {
    __typename: "ContactConnection";
    /**
     * A list of edges.
     */
    edges: (ListContactsQuery_contacts_edges | null)[] | null;
}
export interface ListContactsQuery {
    /**
     * Gets all contacts for the current user
     */
    contacts: ListContactsQuery_contacts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of late, but still someone might find it useful. To decrease amount of null checks (or rather amount of `Maybe<>` types) on the client you have to setup your server side schema appropriately. E.g. in GraphQL .net:

```
    Field<ListGraphType<RoleType>>()
            .Name(QueryName.Roles)
            .Resolve(context => AuthRoleRepo.LoadAllAuthRoles())
            .RequirePermission(Const.Roles.Admin);
```

becomes

```
    Field<NonNullGraphType<ListGraphType<NonNullGraphType<RoleType>>>>()
            .Name(QueryName.Roles)
            .Resolve(context => AuthRoleRepo.LoadAllAuthRoles())
            .RequirePermission(Const.Roles.Admin);
```

Please notice all the `NonNullGraphType` specified for the return type. `ListGraphType<RoleType>` => `NonNullGraphType<ListGraphType<NonNullGraphType<RoleType>>>`

Comment: Yes, while you could always make your schema have less nullable types, this is not desirable because it hurts the ability to evolve the schema https://blog.apollographql.com/graphql-schema-design-building-evolvable-schemas-1501f3c59ed5